# Updated .gitignore file at railstutorial.org

Tags: git

Michael Hartl in the tutorials says an updated .gitignore file is available on the web at rubytutorials.org and that we should go to the website and update our .gitignore file.
I cannot locate it. 
Can someone give a url?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try [this file](https://github.com/mhartl/demo_app/blob/master/.gitignore) from his github project

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download it directly from git hub.